# Trouble Figuring out loading to register with offset from different register

Tags: offset, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, instruction-set

I am creating an 8-bit CPU. I have basic instructions like mov, ld, st, add, sub, mult, jmp. I am trying to put my instructions together. First I move the base address of a value into register 1 (R1). I then want to load register 2 (R2) with the value. So my instructions look:

```
1 mov R1, 0xFFFF
2 ld R2, [R1+0]
```

My opcode definitions are:

```
ld: 0001
mov: 1111
```

Register codes are:

```
R1: 0001
R2: 0010
```

So my instructions in binary look like:

```
1 mov R1, 0xFFFF = 1111 0001 0xFFFF
2 ld R2, [R1+0] = 0001 00010
```

But on my second direction for load, how can I ensure the value stored at the memory location I moved to R1 is going to be used. This is my first time doing anything with computer architecture, so I am a little lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I ensure the value stored at the memory location I moved to R1 is going to be used.

By building your hardware to correctly handle the read-after-write hazard (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)#Data_hazards).

Either

- make it a simple non-pipelined CPU where one instruction writes back to registers before the next instruction reads any registers
- detect the dependency and stall the pipeline
- bypass forwarding.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)#Eliminating_hazards)

Comment: "make it a simple non-pipelined CPU where one instruction writes back to registers before the next instruction reads any registers" This is exactly what I am trying to do but I'm not sure I am doing it correctly. Could you expand just a little?

Comment: @new_programmer_22: your question only describes your instruction-set, not your internal implementation at all.  So the only possible answer is "correctly implement the instruction set so this works like the ISA says it should."  I have no idea how you're trying to implement it, or why you might run into trouble with this.  If this is failing, then your CPU has a hardware bug somewhere, or you're testing it wrong.